Can a clause with subject and verb be a nonessential clause?
I know I can use a relative pronoun as in:
—John, who wants to be a writer, works at a coffee shop.
But is it grammatical to write this sentence?
—Jon works at a coffee shop, maybe one day he’ll be a writer.
Or do I need to place a conjunction or a semicolon?

More natural is two sentences: Jon works at  a coffee shop. Maybe one day he'll be a writer.

correct; without a conjunction or semicolon you have comma splice.

@ Andy Bonner & Lambie. Thank you.

Your sentence in question is not grammatical. It's an example of a common error - a comma splice, defined as an instance of using a comma to link two independent clauses (which should instead be linked by a colon, semicolon, or conjunction. The second clause - that John may one day be a writer - adds no information about the previous clause. He could hope to be an astronaut, a gymnast or a taxidermist and it wouldn't change the fact he works in a coffee shop or tell us any more about it.
Your opening example is probably better described as having a parenthetical clause rather than a 'non-essential' one. They are different, although there can be an overlap. A parenthetical clause is always between two commas which do the same job as parentheses (brackets, like I'm using here). A non-essential clause is one normally introduced by 'which' (as opposed to 'that') and can appear at the end of a sentence so only requires one comma. You couldn't use just one bracket or parenthesis - they have to open and close - so a clause using just one commma could never be called 'parenthetical'.

Thank you for the explanation. You wrote  that a non-essential clause is one normally introduced by 'which' and can appear at the end of a sentence so only requires one comma, but I read that a relative pronoun can only be placed next to the noun that it modifies. Can you please give me an example, so I can understand better? Thank you!

@piermo a non-essential (or non-defining) clause is a type of relative clause. It's non-essential by the nature of the information. For example, "I went for a walk, which was nice". It isn't essential to the statement about the walk to add that it was nice. When you introduce a defining clause - another kind of relative clause - you normally use 'that' and no comma, for example "I enjoyed the walk that I went on today". What follows 'that' defines which walk you mean.

@ Astralbee. I understand what you mean when you wrote that it can appear at the end of a sentence so requires only one comma. In your example which modifies the word walk. Thank you!
